Spyder: Forgo confirmation when removing variable in Variable Explorer
I am using Spyder 5.4.3.  Is there any way to disable the confirmation dialogue box when I remove a variable from the Variable Explorer?  I can disable the confirmation when removing all variables, so I would have expected that I could do the same for the much less dangerous removal of individual variables.
The Preferences window has a tab for the Variable Explorer, but no such switch.  There is  also an IPython Console tab with a switch for disabling the confirmation before deleting all variables, but no such switch for individual variables.
